# System.AccessViolationException: shared_ptr between C# .NET and C++ applications

Tags: c#, c++, shared-ptr

In our project we communicate two applications, one in C# and the other in C++, via named pipes. Our intention is to pass memory pointers between them and be able to access the objects pointed by them in either application. Our current code rises a System.AccessViolationException:

> **System.AccessViolationException:**
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

So far we are using a shared_ptr that points to a custom struct and writting the pointer to the buffer in C++ as seen below:

```
typedef struct {
    int one;
    int a;
    int two;
    int b;
} DATA_STRUCT; // C++ struct
```

---

```
    DATA_STRUCT ds;
    ds.one = 10;
    ds.a = 5;
    ds.two = 99;
    ds.b = 0;

    shared_ptr<DATA_STRUCT> ptr_ds(new DATA_STRUCT);
    shared_ptr<DATA_STRUCT> p(ptr_ds);
    *ptr_ds = ds;

    const int size = BUFFER_SIZE;
    char buf[size];
    memset(buf, 0xCC, 100);
```

---

```
    while (keepReading)
    {
        printf("Write message:");
        scanf("%s", buf);
        memcpy(buf, &p, sizeof(shared_ptr<DATA_STRUCT>));
        if (strcmp(buf, "quit") == 0)
            keepReading = false;
        else
        {
            WriteFile(hPipe1, buf, dwBytesToWrite, &cbWritten, NULL);
            memset(buf, 0xCC, 100);
        }
    }
```

Then, in C# we read the whole buffer, we keep the bytes with the relevant information in another buffer (Rc) and convert the byte array to our custom data structure using unsafe IntPtr as you can see below:

```
    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    bytesRead = clientCSharp.stream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

---

```
public struct DATA_STRUCT
    {
        public int one;
        public int a;
        public int two;
        public int b;
    }; // C# struct
```

---

```
unsafe
{
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, Rc, 0, ReadLength);    
        DATA_STRUCT ds = new DATA_STRUCT();

        IntPtr aux_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));    
        IntPtr final_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));

        Marshal.Copy(Rc, 0, aux_ptr, 4);

        final_ptr = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(aux_ptr, typeof(IntPtr));
        ds = (DATA_STRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(final_ptr, typeof(IntPtr));
}
```

The exception rises when we try to access the final_ptr in order to load the DATA_STRUCT, the last code line presented above. Here I give some Debug images:

C++ Debug image with [Pointer value written to the named pipe buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt62G.png)

C# Debug image with [Pointer value read from the named pipe reduced buffer (Rc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xi73.png)

Could it be something related to the pointer length? As it seems to me in the C++ application it has 8bytes and in the C# application it has 16bytes? Dhould we declare a safe memory location for C# and C++? If yes, then how could it be done?

**Note:** Our goal is to work with the unsafe IntPtr in the C# application. In this example we are loading the DATA_STRUCT object because we wanted to be sure that in the C# application we are retrieving the same object passed in the C++ application. The final applications is meant to be used in Windows.

Comment: This can't work in C++, it doesn't get better when you pinvoke.  Pointers are not valid across process boundaries  Not the only problem, shared_ptr is not just a plain pointer that can be marshaled with IntPtr, there is no interop story for C++ template classes.  You have to flatten the data so it no longer has pointers.  In general takes but a single int that carries the array length, followed by as many copies of the struct data.  Modulo headaches due to type representation and data alignment.  There are libraries that do this for you, like Protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application data spaces are completely distinct, and have been for many years. you can't simply pass a raw pointer between applications and expect to access the same memory.

The normal approach is to serialise the content of your object, squirt it through your pipe and then reconstruct the object at the receiver.

You can set up named shared memory regions, and these are faster to share large objects (in unix, and I assume in windows), but these shared regions will probably not be located at the same address, so still only good for raw data.